# How to use assert module in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, assert

I want an Ansible code that asserts and checks these two interfaces are not equal:

```yaml
bond_interfaces: [eno5, eno6]
```

```yaml
node0125.computer.me: 
          management_ip: x.x.x.x
          management_interface: ens3f0
          bond_interfaces: [eno5, eno6]
          private_ip: x.x.x.x
          # ilo_ip: x.x.x.x
          ansible_host: '{{ management_ip }}'
          tier: balanced
          os_version: 20.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation of [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) a minimal example playbook could look like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    node0125_compute_neda: 
      bond_interfaces: [eno5, eno6]

  tasks:

  - assert:
      that:
        - node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces[0] != node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces[1]
      fail_msg: "Network bond is not over two different interfaces"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [assert] ******************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  msg: All assertions passed
```

or if on the same interface

```yaml
TASK [assert] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces[0] != node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces[1]
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Network bond is not over two different interfaces
```

Since `bond_interfaces: [eno5, eno6]` [is a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables) with two elements, the check will assure that the first list element is not equal the second list element.

If the list will have only two elements, it would also be possible to compare the first with the last element.

```yaml
  - assert:
      that:
        - node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces | length == 2
        - node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces | first != node0125_compute_neda.bond_interfaces | last
      fail_msg: "Network bond is not over two different interfaces"
```

Answer (score 2):

Q: *"Check these two interfece are not equal **bond_interfaces: [eno5, eno6]**"*

A: Filter unique items and compare the length

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: bond_interfaces|unique|length == bond_interfaces|length
        fail_msg: Two or more interfaces repeat in bond_interfaces
        success_msg: All interfaces in bond_interfaces are unique.
```

The above test works with any length of the list *bond_interfaces*.